# Rendering SSRS reports from VB.Net

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

We have a lot of reports on the Intranet that take parameters. All reports are going to be re-built in SSRS. Our goal is to pass all the parameters to the report from the .net application.
What would be the easiest and the fastes way to render reports from .NET application?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using VisualStudio 2008, you should be able to add the MicrosoftReportViewer control to your toolbox and add it to your form designer that way.

If not, you can add a reference to your project to Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms (or .WebForms).

More information is http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252073(VS.80).aspx under the section marked *To add the ReportViewer control to your form*